# jQuery .click() Not Executing for Cloned Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running into a bug with my code. I am cloning a div so that the user can add multiple customers.

```
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            var newNum = new Number(num + 1);   // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
            var newElem = $('#divInput' + num).clone().attr('id', 'divInput' + newNum); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

            // clear input value for cloned items and do not remove text for del button.
            newElem.find('input:not(.DeleteBtn),textarea').val('');
            //newElem.find('input[type="submit"]

            // Replace clone num with incremental num.
            newElem.find(':input').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+/, newNum));
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, newNum));
            });

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#divInput' + num).after(newElem);
```

I have provided a delete button to delete rows and I am using the class name for the button to execute a function on click .

```
        $(".DeleteBtn").click(function () {
            alert(".DeleteBtn Click Function -  " + $(this).attr('id'));
            var DelBtnNum = $(this).attr('id');
            DelBtnNum = DelBtnNum[DelBtnNum.length - 1];
            $('#divInput' + DelBtnNum).remove();

        });
```

I am able to delete the first (original) input row, but any additional customer rows are not deleted.

I have a running demo of the code located here: http://jsfiddle.net/crjunk/FB4BZ/2/

Why will the cloned items not fire the .DeleteBtn.click function?

Comment: have you tried: `.clone(true)` as suggested in DOC ???  http://jsfiddle.net/FB4BZ/3/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for supporting dynamic elements.

Since you have used jQuery 1.6 in the fiddle

```
$(document).delegate(".DeleteBtn", 'click', function () {
    alert(".DeleteBtn Click Function -  " + $(this).attr('id'));
    var DelBtnNum = $(this).attr('id');
    DelBtnNum = DelBtnNum[DelBtnNum.length - 1];
    $('#divInput' + DelBtnNum).remove();

});
```

if jQuery >= 1.7

```
$(document).on('click', ".DeleteBtn", function () {
    alert(".DeleteBtn Click Function -  " + $(this).attr('id'));
    var DelBtnNum = $(this).attr('id');
    DelBtnNum = DelBtnNum[DelBtnNum.length - 1];
    $('#divInput' + DelBtnNum).remove();

});
```

Another option is to clone the element along with the event using `clone(true)`

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks for providing the solution for jQuery 1.7 as well.

Answer (score 11):

Because the default when using clone is to not clone events. Try passing `true` to `clone()`:

```
var newElem = $('#divInput' + num).clone(true).attr('id', 'divInput' + newNum); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sg7Cx/)**

As the [.clone() docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) state:

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents ] ) withDataAndEvents (default: false)

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, delegated handlers are uneccessary when using clone(), as it can clone events and data as well.

Comment: perfect one.. this is simple and perfect

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer, and by far the most elegant

Answer (score 6):

When you bound the click event, only one div existed, so it is the only one that has a click handler.  You should change your code to use on instead of click.

```
$(document).on('click', ".DeleteBtn", function () {
```

Comment: This'll have the same problem you need to delegate to a higher element

Comment: jQuery 1.6.4 in the fiddle

Comment: @Jamiec You are correct.  I always muck up the syntax for on when I need delegation.  Editing to make the code correct.

Answer (score 0):

try going on with .on('click',function(e){ ... }); or use live() selector (but i think live goes deprecated...)

so in your case

`$(".DeleteBtn").on('click',function () { ..`